# Mule 3.8 error: ImportError: No module named auth

Tags: python, firebase-cloud-messaging, mule

I'm trying to get my Python script working inside **Mule 3.8** (it's working in python ide).

When I first added the script and it didn't run, it gave the error ImportError: No module named firebase_admin. This was fixed by adding

> -Dpython.path=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages

to the Arguments > VM Arguments.

After this the error became:

```
  File "<script>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/firebase_admin/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from firebase_admin import credentials
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/firebase_admin/credentials.py", line 19, in <module>
    import google.auth
ImportError: No module named auth
```

In the added folder I have firebase_admin, as well as google/auth. I tried adding both the google as the google/auth to the path, but without success.

I want to send push notifications from Mule.

Comment: Google Auth package is named `google-auth` for pip, and you should import it by doing `import google.auth`, not `import auth`. Both of those things are mentioned in its docs - https://googleapis.dev/python/google-auth/latest/index.html

Comment: @h4z3 I don't import anything myself. Inside credentials.py it does `from google.auth import _helpers` which causes the error I think. Updated my post with more details around the error.

Answer (score 0):

Mule scripting mode uses Jython to execute Python scripts. Anything that depends on installing external modules will fail.

Comment: Okay rip, thanks. I've moved to java in the meantime, hope I get this working.